# Error on newInstance() using fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to use the navigation bar that comes pre-built in Android Studio and found several guides on how to use it but most of them are either outdated or for some reason don't work.

The one I use now seems to "work" but I get an error on newInstance()
Error code:
Error:(58, 59) error: method newInstance in class FirstFragment cannot be applied to given types;
required: String,String
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Here is my code:
    `package welovecode.se.outfitted;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
    implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (position == 0) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, FirstFragment.newInstance())
                .commit();
    } else if (position == 1) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, SecondFragment.newInstance())
                .commit();
    } else if (position == 2) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, ThirdFragment.newInstance())
                .commit();
    }

}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            break;
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}

}
`
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Do you even know the concept of method?

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty informative. You have classes FirstFragment, SecondFragment etc which define newInstance methods that take arguments, in this case two strings. You are however calling those methods without any arguments. 
So the solution should be obvious, either supply the needed arguments, or modify those classes not to require any arguments. It's hard to tell you what exactly you should change in your code because 1) I don't know exactly what you want to accomplish and 2) I don't have the code for your fragments.

Comment: I simply want to switch between the different fragments with the navigation drawer.

Comment: Yes, but, that doesn't really help. Did you write FirstFragment yourself? Or did it come from somewhere else? Where is the source code? What parameters does the constructor take? The error message says two strings. What are they to be used for? 
Are you familiar with basic Java enough to understand the concept of passing parameters to methods?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you want to pass a **Section Number** for your Fragment, like:

```
int sectNum = 100;
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
   .replace(R.id.container, FirstFragment.newInstance( sectNum ))
```

Notes:

- newInstance method call requires an **int** type only.
- You need to determine how to get the section number.